# forms.ModelChoiceField Update view with defualt value

Tags: django-models, view, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have Form ModelChoiceField from ForeignKey model
my Model is:

```
   class Fielinfo(models.Model):
    Perimeter   = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    FidlAbr     = models.CharField(max_length=15,unique=True)
```

and my second model :

```
class Wellinfo(models.Model):
 WellID    = models.CharField(max_length=15,unique=True)
 Perimetre = models.ForeignKey(Fielinfo ,to_field='Perimeter', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and my forms.py is:

```
class NewWells(forms.ModelForm):
 Perimetre = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Fielinfo.objects.all(),label='Perimetre', required=True)
```

the problem is When I need to update my view it doesn't gave me the initial value?
How do I solve this Please? (in the admin area it gave me the initial value).

my views.py is:

```
class PostUpadtW(UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Wellinfo
    template_name = 'Home/WELLINFO/Upd_W.html'
    form_class = NewWells
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user== post.author:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

[image]

Comment: What is the `path(..)` you use?

Comment: path('WellDetail2/<slug:pk>/update/', views.PostUpadtW.as_view(), name='Well-update'),

Comment: why is `pk` a `slug` field, and not an `int` field. Did you pass a valid primary key, (so if you pass `WellDetail2/14/update/` are you sure such object exists?

Comment: the page works good, I have just problem when updating like the image

Answer (score 0):

using ForeignKey is so complicated in Django so i solved it like this;
in models.py

```
class Fielinfo(models.Model):
    Perimeter   = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    FidlAbr     = models.CharField(max_length=15,unique=True)
```

and I changed this

```
class Wellinfo(models.Model):
    WellID    = models.CharField(max_length=15,unique=True)
    Perimetre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and in my forms.py i did this :

```
class NewWells(forms.ModelForm):
    TFTFields =Fielinfo.objects.all()[0:]
    ListField= []
    for fields in TFTFields:
        ListField += [fields.Perimeter]
    ChoiceItems= list(zip(ListField, ListField))
    Perimetre = forms.ChoiceField(label='Perimetre',choices=ChoiceItems)
```

[image]